# A JS alternative to Jinja2 that works on a static server with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, template-engine

I'm developing the front-end of an application using AngularJS on an "old school" server, by that I mean there is no support for Python, Ruby, Java whatsoever. I only have access to a poor phpMyAdmin db and php, and I won't use them.

I'm quite used to the **template engine** of Django (from which Jinja2 is inspired), and I am a big fan of the `block` **inheritance feature**. Unfortunately, AngularJS only provides a regular `include` instruction that simply allows for blocks of codes to be included in the output file.

With Django (Jinja) on the other hand, you can easily do something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // ... some stuff that should be done on every page
    </script>
</html>
```

and for every page of your website

```
{% extends "core/skeleton.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>This is my content...</h1>
    <p>
        ...and I don't care about the rest.
    </p>
{% endblock content %}
```

which I found very powerful.

With AngularJS only, you would end up with 2 `include` statements to achieve the same result. Plus the more blocks you want to nest within the page, the more `include` statements you need to use (actually, every Django `block` would lead to 2 `ìnclude` statements in AngularJS).

What would be **the most appropriate template engine** that meets my requirements? Namely:

- **Written in JS** so that it can be run on a "static" server
- With the **block inheritance** feature
- **Light**
- That **does not clash with AngularJS**

Comment: Not sure if it works with Angular but if you love Jinja2, checkout http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go this route, you can use jade templates and compile them into html at build time with something likehttps://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-jade

Jade has an `extend` and `include` directive.

You may be fighting angular by doing this. UiRouter provides compositional and nested states, abstract states and named views.